# How to send Amazon Chime messages automatically?

Tags: python, bots, amazon-chime

I want to schedule the sending of Amazon Chime messages and send them automatically. For instance, I want message1 to be sent every Monday at 10am, message2 to be sent every Tuesday at 15pm, etc...

Should I need to do it via a bot and Python ? What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to schedule your functions like this:

```py
import schedule
import time

def message1():
    # Sends msg1

def message2():
    # Sends msg2

schedule.every().monday.at("10:00").do(message1)
schedule.every().tuesday.at("15:00").do(message2)
```

Comment: That's what I thought, thank you. But is the execution of this script blocking other scripts ? I have a bunch of other scripts running via the windows task scheduler.

Comment: Nothing is blocking, you can have as many schedules as you like to. If I answer your question please tag it as answered. Thank you